# Syntax help in fstab needed

Tags: partitioning, mount, usb-drive, fstab, fdisk

I just added a external ssd-drive (USB) to my VM (Ubuntu 20.04).

Im trying to set it up as a XFS repository, and got the creation of A XFS partition (sdb1) in /sdb working. But i cant figure out how to mount the drive in fstab.

This is what blkid gives:

```
/dev/sdb1: UUID="b256b52a-695a-471b-a1cb-76b0d99eb01a" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="25412a7a-01"
```

When im using a internal drive in VMWare, i use the syntax like this without problem:

```
'UUID=b532f390-071c-48b7-a8e5-28ca5ee23f5a /mnt/veeamrepo xfs nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Im still learning this, but i cant figure it out. Anyone around to give a hint?

Also, how come /sdb1 is created, why cant i just format /sdb with XFS as when i use a internal drive?

Regards

/Peter

Comment: The line under "syntax like this" is actually a line followed by a command. The command should not be part of `/etc/fstab` obviously. Please edit your question and clear this up.

Comment: Also, please don't ask two questions in the same post. Are you mixing up drives and partitions? You don't mount a drive, you mount a partition.

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/fstab line will look like:

```
UUID=b256b52a-695a-471b-a1cb-76b0d99eb01a /mnt/mountpoint-dir-name xfs nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

You get to decide the `mountpoint-dir-name`, of course.

---

You can also experiment using the `mount` command. Lots of folks do this in order to test before adding to /etc/fstab. The information is the same, but the syntax is slightly different (note the `--fake` flag for testing):

```
mount --fake -t xfs -o nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show /dev/disk/by-uuid/b256b52a-695a-471b-a1cb-76b0d99eb01a /mnt/mountpoint-dir-name
```

Comment: Thanx, this is exactly what i needed! Cheers